# How do I easily and neatly print multiple objects using a toString method, that are also aligned?

Tags: java, layout, tostring

I've got an ArrayList of members, each with their own information including name, age, date of birth etc., which is called with a toString method when printed out to the terminal.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "|ID: " + id + "| Name: " + name + "| Age: " + 
              calculateAge(age, LocalDate.now()) + "| Tlf.: " + tlfNo + "| Active: " + 
              activeMember + "| Next payment: " + nextPayment + "|";
    }
```

And here's the output:

```
|ID: 12| Name: Casper| Age: 49| Tlf.: 12345678| Active: true| Next payment: 2018-02-12|
|ID: 13| Name: Allan| Age: 69| Tlf.: 12345678| Active: true| Next payment: 2018-01-12|
|ID: 16| Name: Christina| Age: 100| Tlf.: 12345678| Active: false| Next payment: 2018-02-04|
|ID: 19| Name: RICK| Age: 49| Tlf.: 12345678| Active: false| Next payment: 2018-04-14|
```

How do I get the different pieces of information to align on top of each other?

Comment: `String.format`

Comment: @Naman but you will need to know the max for each

Comment: is `tfl` _always_ 8 digits?

Comment: @Eugene sorry, didn't get you for the word `max`. did you mean the length of the characters?

Comment: @Naman yes, but it seems that if `tfl` field is always 8 digits, you would only need to know the max name...

Comment: @Naman you probably want to pad the string with spaces, so you need to now the max lenght of each field.

Comment: In terms of strings, it has to be maximum characters in each value of varied types that are to be known to pad with spaces, agreed. Just suggesting `String.format` would still be the way to start looking to improve the current piece. @StephanHogenboom

Comment: @Eugene Yes, actually 'name' is the only piece of information which has a variable length.

Comment: ID too, of course, since you don't know how many you will have.

Comment: Unless you always want to reserve the maximum space for every value type, e.g. eleven characters for every `int`, the `toString()` method is the wrong place for it. The `toString()` method implements a context free operation. Formatting all elements of a `List` with a proper alignment, is an entirely different operation.

Comment: @Eugene ah yes, of course. Although this is simply a school project so the max number of ID digits won't exceed 2.

Comment: @Holger So could I make a method purely for the formatting of the string (i.e. formattedString() ) within the same class as the toString() method and then have the toString method call the formattedString() method?

Comment: @malthe.w yes, that would be a reasonable approach, assuming that `formattedString()` has a parameter object containing the maximum sizes, determined for a particular list in a preceding step. It would be even better, if the class also provides the factory method for such record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 public String toString() {
        return String.format("|id: %10d |Name: %30s| Age: %02d | Tlf.: %d| Active: %s| Next Payment: %s |", id, getNameTrimmed() , age , tlfNo ,    activeMember, nextPayment );
 }

 private  String getNameTrimmed(){
    if(name.length()>30) {
        return name.substring(0,27)+"...";
    }
    return name;
}
```

This way the id will have 10 characters (it will still break the format if you have longer IDs)
The name will have 30 so you need to add a method to give you 30 chars name

Comment: Looks promising, however I want the spaces after the name, not in between 'Name:' and the name input. What's the syntax for that?

Comment: add a - sign to the format. For ID it will become %-10d and for name %-30s

Answer (score 1):

you can create a method for that, since `toString` simply, will not work:

```
static String printPojos(Pojo... pojos) {
    int maxName = Arrays.stream(pojos)
                        .map(Pojo::getName)
                        .mapToInt(String::length)
                        .max()
                        .orElse(0);

    int maxId = Arrays.stream(pojos)
                      .mapToInt(x -> x.getName().length())
                      .max()
                      .orElse(0);

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner("\n");
    for (Pojo pojo : pojos) {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("|");
        sj.add("ID: " + Strings.padEnd(Integer.toString(pojo.getId()), maxId, ' '));
        sj.add(" Name: " + Strings.padEnd(pojo.getName(), maxName, ' '));
        sj.add(" Age: " + Strings.padEnd(Integer.toString(pojo.getAge()), 3, ' '));
        sj.add(" Active: " + Strings.padEnd(Boolean.toString(pojo.isActive()), 5, ' '));

        result.merge(sj);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I am using `Strings::padEnd` (from `guava`, but this is fairly easy to write even without an external library).

`Pojo` in my case looks like this:

```
static class Pojo {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final boolean active;

    // constructor, getters

}
```

And the result looks like:

```
    Pojo one = new Pojo("Casper", 49, true, 1);
    Pojo two = new Pojo("Allan", 100, true, 10_000);

    System.out.println(printPojos(one, two));



ID: 1    | Name: Casper| Age: 49 | Active: true 
ID: 10000| Name: Allan | Age: 100| Active: true
```

Comment: I like your solution, im not that familiar with Guava. I will go look it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple implementation for your problem, which does not require external libraries. If you want use external libs there are enough methods available in Apache-commons or Guava for instance. It could probably be done smarter but this will do the trick:

```
class Member {

  String id;
  String name;
  int age;
  LocalDate date;
  int tlfNo;
  boolean activeMember;
  LocalDate nextPayment;

  public Member(String id, String name, int age, int tlfNo, boolean activeMember, LocalDate nextPayment) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.tlfNo = tlfNo;
    this.activeMember = activeMember;
    this.nextPayment = nextPayment;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("|ID: %s| Name: %s| Age: %s| Tlf.: %s| Active: %s| Next payment: %s|", 
      doFormat(id, "id", 10), doFormat(name, "name", 10),             
      doFormat(String.valueOf(age), "age", 10), 
      doFormat(String.valueOf(tlfNo), "tlfNo", 10), 
      doFormat(String.valueOf(activeMember), "active", 10),             
      doFormat(nextPayment.toString(), "nextPayment", 20));
  }

  String doFormat(String value, String fieldName, int maxLenght) {
    if (value.length() > maxLenght) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("cannot format string longer than %s for %s, value = %s", maxLenght, fieldName, value));
    }
    return padLeftSpaces(value, maxLenght);
  }

  public String padtLefSpaces(String inputString, int length) {
    if (inputString.length() >= length) {
      return inputString;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sb.length() < length - inputString.length()) {
      sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(inputString);

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

The idea is that you pad all the field with spaces and only replace space that are occupied. The pad left method is borrowed from [bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pad-string)

Comment: That’s a really strange solution, considering that `String.format` is capable of doing the padding that you are doing manually in `padLeftSpaces`.

Comment: @Holger Agreed, i was not aware `String.format` was capable of padding automatically. Guess i also learned something from trying to solve this question.